# Why does my car slip from drive to neutral by itself?

Tags: ford, automatic-transmission, fiesta

Hello my name is Evelyn and I have a 2015 Ford Fiesta SE that I bought new. When I first got the car is had trouble shifting, it acted like a 4 speed car. What I mean is it would whine when it changed gears. I have taken back to dealership many times and they said there was nothing wrong with it.. Now when you drive it it slips into nuetural while your driving and you have to put it in neutral and back in drive in order for it to move forward. Please can you help me?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Realistically, this is something I'd take up with Ford directly. It sounds to me like you got the shaft from the dealership where you bought it from. By taking it up with a regional Ford rep, you should get some kind of positive response. Ensure you tell them you've taken it to the dealership several times with the "it's okay" response, yet now there's bigger issues which are more than likely related to the original issue. You don't state how many miles on on the Fiesta, but really, the car isn't that old. This kind of stuff really ticks me off.